# EF Fluent API tutorial

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first, fluent

I want to learn Entity framework 4.1 Fluent API. Can you please send me goos links ?

Comment: There seems to be a dearth of tutorials regarding this for some reason. Thanks for the great suggestions, guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ADO.NET team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/) has a lot of information on getting started.  There's a good [series of articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-1-introduction-and-model.aspx) on the CTP5 release.

Also try [Entity Framework  Design](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/) and the [Data developer center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723).

And then there's always [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+learn+entity+framework)

Comment: I also found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698) specifically to be helpful.